# Is there a grid trading option for Ethereum DEX'es like uniswap and sushiswap?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, sushiswap, trading

Currently DEX'es like uniswap and sushiswap can only do basic swap orders, but is there a service or way to do grid trading using these types of DEX'es? Or is there another L2 that can do this? Basically grid trading on chain.

Answer (score 2):

I would be very interested too. If you find any information, don't hesitate to post. I just found this, doing a quick search: https://medium.com/degate/degate-dex-launches-testnet-with-spot-limit-orders-and-grid-trading-4f05702f2d45

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).